# Using game center in corona sdk

Tags: ios, xcode, coronasdk, game-center

Does the game center work in an app built by corona when I test it in a physical device ? I tested my app that should access to the game center but that doesn't happen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Game Center with Corona SDK apps. Testing is tricky. You have to logout of your real GC account and login with your test account. Then you will be in sandbox mode and you can then test your app.

Comment: What do u mean by test account ? I have loged out and tried another account but that didn't work

Comment: create a new Apple ID. Run your app. When you are prompted to login, use the account you created. You have to use a Developer provisioning profile, not a distribution profile for this to work..

Comment: The proplem is that I don't even get prompted to login !